# Coding Java in non english language, for eg Spanish or Japanese

Tags: java

Is it possible to code Java in a language other than English?.
I am not asking about the logs messages which may be shown in another language.
If possible does it requires a different compiler ( or JDK with different language support).?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? A translated version, where every Object/method/... is translated to eg Spanish?

Comment: The answer is **No**.

Comment: Do you mean the ability to name your methods, or the translation of the language and the JDK (the "standard functions", like `System.out.println`)?

Comment: Imagine if developers around the world all produced localized source code... That would be nice to debug on an international project :)

Comment: I remember MS tried that on VBA on some old MSOffice version. They didn't do it again.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato : I didn't mean naming the user defined methods. My question is about "Standard functions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Go through this para if you know some theory about compilers otherwise read next para`.
When a compiler is to be written,keywords and other symbols are already pre-defined and the lexical analyzer matches them and stores them in the symbol table and subsequent phases are then followed before finally developing a machine code.

The answer to your question is both `NO` and `YES`.

`NO` because `James Gosling and his team` developed Java JDK with English keywords so you have to follow that if you are using his JDK.

`YES` because you can develop your own Java Compiler with different keywords in different language.But that will definitely not be called Java Compiler but another compiler using OOPS concepts.

Comment: Another solution can be to write a "translator". The "translator" takes java-Spanish and "translate" it in java. For example with ANTLR you can take a Java grammar, translate his tokens in Spanish and then  you have your Spanish Java. From the Java-Spanish grammar you can generate a parser that takes Spanish Java as input and produces as output standard Java.

Comment: Yes , `Bootstrapping` is another option. Thanks @Fedy2

Comment: You should consider using *italics* for *emphasis* instead of `code statements`, which are intended for, well, code and keywords :).

Answer (score 2):

I have one suggestion. you define a word mapping to map all the available, acceptable java keywords to your language.

```
public => publique
static => statique
```

like this. Then do word processing. convert your language to english in background and generate java files in english language. Compile those java classes.

I'm not verymuch confident about this approach. This may give a small idea. Pardon me if I'm talking something else than what you are looking for. If you have any thoughts on it, kindly let me know. I'm interested working in this project.

Comment: We will encounter some problems while importing other classes since the other class names will be in english. you need to build the word dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. You can name the identifiers whatever you like , provided they are legal as per the language specs, but the keywords,API methods etc. will always be the same. They should be used in its original form. Hence you cannot substitute the Spanish equivalent of word *throw* in place of `throw` in Java .

Probably read [Grammars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.1).

Answer (score 0):

This is Not Possible. Java Code write in only English Language.

Comment: Technically you can't unless you write your own parser that translates only the tokens.